# Android screen orientation change video restart

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am working on an activity playing a video when ever i change the screen orientation the video restarts. I want when a user change the orientation the video should start from that point only. the activity should not restart.

My Code :

```
public class Activity_Play_Video extends Activity {

VideoView videoView;
String uri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity__play__video);
//        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Intent intent1 = getIntent();
    String stream = intent1.getStringExtra("Stream_url");
    uri = "http://s5.wwl.tv/wowzastroage/content/" + stream + ".mp4";
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    videoView.setVideoPath(uri);
    Log.e("####", uri);
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this, true));
    videoView.start();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity__play__video);
    } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity__play__video);
    }
}
}
```

Menifest :

```
     <activity
 android:name="com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.sampleapp.Activity_Play_Video"
 android:label="@string/title_activity_activity__play__video"
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `onConfigurationChanged()` method **save the current time of your video** in **shared preferences** and in `onCreate()` method **check if you have any saved time in shared preferences or not.**

If `yes` then seek to that time and start your video.

You can use `following code` to jump to a specific time.

```
videoView.seekTo(int msec);
```

And to get current time of your video you can do it like this:

```
long duration=videoView.getDuration();
```

Comment: i will give it a try.

Comment: i think the best practice would be save the time in `onSaveInstanceState()` and get it again in `onCreate()` method